# doxygen file list does not link to files

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am generating html for my c++ project using doxygen. Doxygen generates a file list page, but none of the listed header files link to their documentation page. For example, in the file list found at http://rbdl.bitbucket.org/files.html, all the header.h files link to their file reference documentation page. My listed files are not linked.

How to I make my generated doxygen file list page have linked headers also?

Comment: are you using doxywizard?

Comment: I had a similar issue and the problem was that doxygen was not actually indexing anything in my source files. I believe that adding `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` to the doxygen configuration fixed the problem. I'm not a doxygen expert by any stretch, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that the files were not commented with a "\file" doxygen comment. After adding these "\file" annotation to the file, the file list linked to a page listing the classes etc listed in the file.

@iboisver was also correct, that EXTRACT_ALL=YES forced all files to be linked even if they did not have the "\file" annotation.